# textbox values on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three textboxes with the same id's in a table. I also have one dropdown on top of the table. While changing the dropdown I need to set the textbox values as same as the dropdown value.

I used the following code and I am able to change only the first textbox, others are not getting values.

```
function myHome() {
    var zoneId = $("#funderIds").val();
    $("#funder").val($("#funderIds").val());
}
```

```html
<select id="funderIds" name="funderIds" onchange="myHome()" style="width: 25%;">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>                           
    <option value="3">option1</option>                          
    <option value="5">option2</option>                          
    <option value="6">option3</option>                          
</select>

<input type="text" name="funder" id="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder" id="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder" id="funder" value="">
```

Can anyone give some advise on where I am making a mistake?

Comment: you can only use and `id` only once

Comment: Id should be unique. you can use class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid to use same *ID* for more than one element, it should be unique throughout the document, thus use *class* instead!

**ID's are unique**

1. Each element can have only one ID
2. Each page can have only one element with that ID

**Classes are NOT unique**

1. You can use the same class on multiple elements.
2. You can use multiple classes on the same element.

---

Change your code to:

```
function myHome() {
    var zoneId = $("#funderIds").val();
    $(".funder").val($("#funderIds").val());
}

<select id="funderIds" name="funderIds" onchange="myHome()" style="width:25%;">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>                           
    <option value="3">option1</option>                          
    <option value="5">option2</option>                          
    <option value="6">option3</option>                          
</select>


<input type="text" name="funder-1" id="funder-1" class="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder-2" id="funder-2" class="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder-3" id="funder-3" class="funder" value="">
```

Comment: Can I get the zoneId values as "option1" or  "option2" or  "option3"? Now I am getting this values as 3,5,6.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen,To get text of option, use $('#"#funderIds" option:selected').text();

Answer (score 1):

Id has to be unique, try `name` instead with min changes:

```
function myHome() {
     var zoneId = $("#funderIds").val();
     $("input[name=funder]").val(zoneId);
}
```

Edited:

To get option text, use `:selected`:

```
function myHome() {
    var zoneId = $("#funderIds option:selected").text();
    $("input[name=funder]").val(zoneId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique identifier,they should always be unique. If you have multiple elements with same ID, ID selector (`$(".funder")` in your case) will return the object of first element only.

You can rather use same class and use class selector to target all the element.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="funder" class="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder" class="funder" value="">
<input type="text" name="funder" class="funder" value="">
```

**JS:**

```
function myHome() {
    var zoneId = $("#funderIds").val();
    $(".funder").val(zoneId );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myHome() {
var zoneId = $("#funderIds").val();
$(".funder").val(zoneId);
```

}

```
<select id="funderIds" name="funderIds" onchange="myHome()"               style="width:25%;">
<option value="0">--Select--</option>                           
<option value="3">option1</option>                          
<option value="5">option2</option>                          
<option value="6">option3</option>
```